# Make vim properly indent piped while loop

Tags: vim, indentation

I have been using this line of code for reading ip `1.1.1.1` in `ip_list.txt`, store in variable `line` then print out:

```
if [ true == false ]; then # Example
ip="1.1.1.1"
grep -r $ip ip_list.txt | while read -r line ; do
echo "Line is: $line"
done
fi
```

Code is working great but vim doesn't indent this code properly. When I do, `g=GG`, you can see the `done` syntax should be lined up below `grep` syntax but it went to the left with `if` statement. It will indent like this in vim:

```
if [ true == false ]; then
    ip="1.1.1.1"
    grep -r $ip ip_list.txt | while read -r line ; do
    echo "Line is: $line"
done # Went to the left. Not lined up with grep
fi
```

Even if I removed the `;` , and let the `do` at the bottom like this:

```
if [ true == false ]; then # Example
ip="1.1.1.1"
grep -r $ip ip_list.txt | while read -r line
do
echo "Line is: $line"
done
fi
```

the `done` syntax still not indent properly in vim code editor (now if I do `g=GG`):

```
if [ true == false ]; then
        ip="1.1.1.1"
        grep -r $ip ip_list.txt | while read -r line
do
        echo "Line is: $line"
done # not lined up with grep syntax
fi
```

Any way to edit this code so vim can indent it properly ?

The expected output should be:

```
if [ true == false ]; then
    ip="1.1.1.1"
    grep -r $ip ip_list.txt | while read -r line ; do
        echo "Line is: $line"
    done
fi
```

OR it should be

```
if [ true == false ]; then
    ip="1.1.1.1"
    grep -r $ip ip_list.txt | while read -r line
    do
        echo "Line is: $line"
    done
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by _Vim doesn't indent_? If I open a new empty `file.sh` in vim, paste this 4-lines file, and then do `gg=G`, then all lines start at the first column, which is still undesirable, I guess, but the way you describe. Please, consider recording a session with [asciinema](https://asciinema.org/).

Comment: I updated the code to prove indention problem when it's inside if statement. You can see the `done` syntax should be lined up with the `grep` syntax but it went far to the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vim's indenting regex isn't smart enough for that. You can edit the syntax file yourself if you'd like: use `:scriptnames` to see the files that get loaded by vim to see the full path of the `syntax/sh.vim` file.

A simpler method would be changing your bash syntax:

```sh
if [ true == false ]; then # Example
ip="1.1.1.1"
while read -r line; do
echo "Line is: $line"
done < <(grep -r $ip ip_list.txt )
fi
```

gets correctly indented to

```sh
if [ true == false ]; then # Example
  ip="1.1.1.1"
  while read -r line; do
    echo "Line is: $line"
  done < <(grep -r $ip ip_list.txt )
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I think best should change the syntax as you mentioned, not going to mess the vim config.

Comment: Wait a minute, I have question regarding on this. What does the < < symbol means ? Why double symbol ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html

Comment: Ok the accepted answer here has example and help me to understand why the double symbol: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe